# cytoscapeJS classname selector overriding non-matching classname selector

Tags: cytoscape.js

I am using a classnames to distinguish between different node types, but cytoscapeJS is always using the first classname it encounters in the element list.

Here's my element array:

```
[{
    "group": "nodes",
    "data": {
        "id": 2,
        "label": "users-iphone"
    },
    "classes": ["client"],
    "selected": false,
    "selectable": false,
    "locked": false,
    "grabbable": false
}, {
    "group": "nodes",
    "data": {
        "id": 3,
        "label": "FLOOR-01-N"
    },
    "classes": ["ap"],
    "selected": false,
    "selectable": false,
    "locked": false,
    "grabbable": false
}, {
    "group": "nodes",
    "data": {
        "id": 4,
        "label": "FLOOR-01-SW"
    },
    "classes": ["switch"],
    "selected": false,
    "selectable": false,
    "locked": false,
    "grabbable": false
}, {
    "group": "nodes",
    "data": {
        "id": 5,
        "label": "MAIN-ROUTER"
    },
    "classes": ["router"],
    "selected": false,
    "selectable": false,
    "locked": false,
    "grabbable": false
}]
```

and the stylesheet: (variables are substituted at runtime)

```
node.client {
    border-color: ${colorClient};
    background-image: url('images/client.svg');
}

node.ap {
    border-color: ${colorAp};
    background-image: url('images/ap.svg');
};

node.switch {
    border-color: ${colorSwitch};
    background-image: url('images/switch.svg');
}

node.router {
    border-color: ${colorRouter};
    background-image: url('images/router.svg');
}
```

When rendered, the nodes all get the style for 'node.client'.

I tried using both the raw JSON and 'string' formats for the style sheet.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out it’s a bug in the latest version (3.5.3):

https://github.com/cytoscape/cytoscape.js/issues/2356